# Can ı restart regular ros2 node?

Tags: python, ros, ros2

I need the check ROS2 sensor node. when sensor in fail state, i want to restart sensor node.

I learn ROS2 has a 2 node types. Regular node and Lifecycle node. But my sensor package doesn't publish the node with using Lifecycle node. And i'm using now killing the node with process ID and restarting with using python subprocess. I think this can't usable solution. But i can't find other solution. Do you know kill, restart , start ROS2 regular node with  using ros2 packages or libraries.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [thread](https://answers.ros.org/question/382043/ros2-respawn/) about respawn. You could use the `respawn` tag in the `launch file`, like:

```
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node


def generate_launch_description():
    return LaunchDescription([
        Node(
            package='orca_base',
            executable='fake_barometer.py',
            output='screen',
            name='fake_barometer',
            respawn=True,
            respawn_delay=4,
        )])
```

Comment: This respawn parameters restart the node in which time. For example i'm using sllidar and when im remove the usb, node has still running and topic has still be in topic list. Is restart the node when using parameters for this example?

Comment: No, i tried this and not solve my problem :/.

Comment: I can check if this is version related ... which ROS2 and OS are you using?

Comment: This solution will only work if the node quits/crashes on its own and not if it is still running. My solution would be to write my own [lifecycle node](https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/humble/lifecycle/README.rst) as a wrapper around the original sensor class.

Comment: Ahhh the fail state is actually a valid state !?

Comment: Then a lifecycle or having a service to restart the node should be the way. There is a package for ROS1 though, called [`rosmon`](http://wiki.ros.org/rosmon), maybe that could serve as some inspiration as well

Comment: i couldn't find like rosmon library, in ros1 we kill node with using rosnode kill but this removing in ros2. Thanks for reply @ignacio

Comment: I researching this thank you for the thought. Any example for this solution. @Darkproduct

Comment: Here is [something about life cycle nodes](http://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html). Together with the documentation in my first comment this should be everything you need. For reference you can also [look at this](https://github.com/RoverRobotics-archive/ros2_bno055_driver). And it the failed state is valid depends on how the node is written. Does it crash or just stall? If it really crashes or terminates the launch file flag from this answer should work.